# onEdit trigger e.range only one cell instead of whole selection

Tags: google-apps-script

If I select several cells (e.g. A1:D5) and type some text to trigger onEdit(e), how can I get the selected range? All these functions (e.range, .getActiveRange, .getActiveSelection) only return the one cell that has the new text (A1)!

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log('A1 Notation: ' + e.range.getA1Notation());

  // Try workaround using getActiveSheet. Also fails within the onEdit function.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var selection = sheet.getActiveSelection();

  Logger.log('getActiveRange A1 Notation: ' + range.getA1Notation());
  Logger.log('getActiveSelection A1 Notation: ' + selection.getA1Notation());
}
```

If I hit the delete key instead of typing text, the range functions work as expected (A1:D5).

Answer (score 2):

With a range selected, when you press delete the contents of all selected cells are deleted, therefore you receive an event with a range affecting all selected cells.  When you enter text into a cell, only the one cell is affected and therefore you get an event with a range of a single cell.

If you want to test this, try stretching a range.  You will notice that the event range will only be for the affected cells and not the whole selected area.

P.S. - If you would like to select a region and manipulate the contents without trying to handle it inside an event, you should be able to create a custom function and have it appear in the Spreadsheet UI.  Like so:

```
function onOpen(){
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('Top menu name')
   .addItem('menu item description 1', 'functionName1' )
   .addItem('menu item description 2', 'functionName2')
   .addToUi();   
}

functionName1(){ ...... }

etc....
```

Comment: Yes, deleting a range (or pasting into a range) affects every cell in the range, so it makes sense that e.range grabs the whole range then.
 
How can I get the selected range of a spreadsheet from within an onEdit(e) function triggered by only one of the selected cells being edited? 

I'm automating a rooms schedule sheet. I want to be able to create calendar events directly from the sheet by selecting the range that corresponds to the room row and time columns, then typing the event name.

Comment: Restrictions: Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions:  They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/ .  Please, step out of the event mechanic.  Try selecting your range and using a custom function to perform this task.